# Why can I not activate the spell wheel in LEGO Harry Potter Years 5-7?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

During the game I can´t take out the spell wheel, I keep pressing <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> on the Wii remote/nunchuk and it doesn't come out, so it's impossible to play.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How far into the game are you?  During the first mission, and [up until the end of the first class lesson](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35768/how-do-i-unlock-the-spells-from-years-1-4-in-lego-harry-potter-years-5-7), you are unable to switch spells.  The students default to **Wingardium Leviosa** and the adults default to **Reducto**.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know I wasn't able to change spells till the first class! I was a little paranoid because I had read that some versions of the game had glitches and sveral problems. Now I feel stupid xD Thank you again!

Comment: No problem.  Enjoy the game, and welcome to Gaming SE!

Comment: The story contrives to take away all your spells at the beginning, you will have to relearn _everything_.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to **hold** the "C" button in order for it to display, and then use the thumbstick to choose a spell, and then press "Z" to cast it.

If it isn't working properly, you may want to call Time Warner tech support, apparently many of the discs that went out for this game were bad, and they are experiencing a [variety of bugs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36353/during-year-6-my-harry-potter-years-5-7-game-freezes-on-wii-is-there-a-work-ar).

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, That's what I do, i press the C button and it's supposed to come out, that's the problem. I've sent an e-mail to Lego and I hope they answer it soon. Thank you!