# Why can't I access the key during the first Defence Against the Dark Arts class?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I am stuck in the Defence Against the Dark Arts classroom in LEGO Harry Potter: Years 5-7.  I have unlocked the potion and collected everything, but the sparkly arrow is pointing to the locked door, and when I send the pet up the tube and walk along the ledge, the key I need is not knocked down.

Can anyone help me get the key?

Comment: Have you tried both pets available at that point (Crookshanks and Ron's owl)?  It could be that you just aren't getting close enough to the key to knock it down for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure you drank the potion?  A responder in this link http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38875/10260 notes that they sometimes missed it even though they thought they had done it.